# APEX - Initialize sub classes in a constructor

Tags: apex, wrapper-class, constructor

I am trying to find a solution to initialize a subclass in a constructor, but I have the following error
message : **Variable does not exit: Info**

```
public class Products {
    public String Name;
    public class Info{
        public String price;
        public String testField;
    }
    public Products(Products.Info myInfo){
        this.Info = myInfo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner class is contained in the outer class, but it is not a *member* of the outer class (that is, it occupies no storage space). To have one or more info members, you need to define them:

```
public class Products {
    public String Name;
    public Info info; // an instance member named info of type Info
    public class Info{
        public String price;
        public String testField;
    }
    public Products(Products.Info myInfo){
        this.Info = myInfo;
    }
}
```

Note that there's nothing special about the member *name*, you can call it whatever you want:

```
public class Products {
    public String Name;
    public Info productInfo; // an instance member named productInfo of type Info
    public class Info{
        public String price;
        public String testField;
    }
    public Products(Products.Info myInfo){
        this.productInfo = myInfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much !